# FIXED ROSCORE Error when trying to run

Tags: ros2, rviz, ros-humble, roscore

**[FIXED] Both comments under this post solved the issue, i was trying to
run rviz with the command rviz and not rviz2 and it turns out i had a weird mix of ROS 1 and ROS 2 so uninstalling and reinstalling the intended one helped a lot and also i had my source command in the bashrc file and removing it also helped!** IMAGES: [rviz error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOlmo.png) [roscore error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y9yH.png) So im trying to open rviz but i get the error `Could not contact ROS master at [http://localhost:11311], retrying...` so i searched online and found out that roscore isnt running but when i try to run it i get the error below. I have no clue what is wrong and im very very new to ROS and this is my first time using it. Any help?

```
  File "/usr/bin/roscore", line 37, in <module>
    from roslaunch.nodeprocess import DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_SIGINT, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_SIGTERM
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from .scriptapi import ROSLaunch
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/scriptapi.py", line 42, in <module>
    import roslaunch.parent
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 54, in <module>
    import roslaunch.server
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/roslaunch/server.py", line 80, in <module>
    from rosgraph_msgs.msg import Log
ImportError: cannot import name 'Log' from 'rosgraph_msgs.msg' (/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rosgraph_msgs/msg/__init__.py)
?
```

Comment: It seems you have two conflicting ROS versions. `roscore` is from ROS 1 and the last ImportError points to ROS 2 humble. I suggest removing all installation, and starting again with the intended one. Also, please remove lines like `source /opt/ros/ros_distro/setup.bash` from your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: To add to the above answer, in ROS 2 (Humble, and others), RViz is launched with the `rviz2` command.